# Calling a PHP Function from a HTML <Select> option

Tags: php, html

I have a `<select>` element with 3 options within it and also have 3 PHP functions. How can I set it so that when each option is pressed a different PHP function is called? By my understanding, the select options are client side and the functions are server side. Does this mean that AJAX is necessary? Is there a way to do this without AJAX?

```
<select name="mySelect">
  <option value="filter-oa" disabled="disabled" selected>Filter by Open Access</option>
  <option value="full">Fully Open Access</option>
  <option value="offers">Offers Open Access</option>
  <option value="none">No Open Access</option>
</select>
```

My 3 functions are: `getProOA(), getProFullOA(), and getProNoOA()`
Example: User selects the "Fully Open Access" option within the drop-down menu and the `getProFullOA()` function is called and lists the products on the page.

Comment: You have to use AJAX to do this unless you want to allow the page to reload. If you have never used AJAX before there are *tons* of tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this to work you'll need to post the form to the server:

```
<?php

if (!empty($_POST['mySelect'])) {
  // this block is only executed if values are received

  switch ($_POST['mySelect']) {
    case 'filter-oa': 
      getProOA();
      break;

    case 'full':
      getProFullOA();
      break;

    case 'none':
      getProNoOA();
      break;

    case 'offers':
      echo 'some offer';
      break;

    default:
      echo 'ERROR';
  }

  die();
}

?>
<form method="POST">
<select name="mySelect">
  <option value="filter-oa" disabled="disabled" selected>Filter by Open Access</option>
  <option value="full">Fully Open Access</option>
  <option value="offers">Offers Open Access</option>
  <option value="none">No Open Access</option>
</select>  
<button type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this without a button to submit? Maybe onClick?

Comment: Are your functions in javascript or PHP ? because its easy to do in javascript with 'onchange' event

Comment: @BenoitF They are PHP functions.

Comment: Yes. Still have the `select` inside a `form` but you could add a `onchange` handler on the `select`: `<select onchange="this.form.submit()">`

Answer (score 1):

```
<select name="mySelect">
  <option value="filter-oa" disabled="disabled" selected>Filter by Open Access</option>
  <option value="full">Fully Open Access</option>
  <option value="offers">Offers Open Access</option>
  <option value="none">No Open Access</option>
</select>
```

Here try to use a simple ajax call:

```
   $(select[name='mySelect']).on('change', function(){
        let val = $('select').find('option[value="' + this.value + '"]');
    })
    let dataString = "callFunction=" + val
   $.ajax({
      url: "Your_php_file.php",
      type: POST,
      data: dataString
    }).done(function(result) {
      $('.where-you-want-the-output').html(result);
    });
```

Just add this to your code!

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Sorry, not familiar with Ajax, for this approach do the functions need to be in a separate PHP file?

Comment: The functions can be in the same php file **e.g. index.php** but you just need to 
`$_REQUEST['callFunction']` and use that to call your function

Comment: Can I remove the "url:" and " $('.where-you-want-the-output').html(result);" to keep everything on the same page and prevent reloading?

Comment: The url is where you want your request to be sent e.g `url: 'index.php'`. This won't reload the page ajax will go off and call the function in the background and return the data to you in the `.done(function(result){})` so if you want to display that data in a div with a class you just `.done(function(result){$('.divWithClass').html(result)})` This will output your `echo` / `return` that you have in the php function